# Input box above autocomplete menu - Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete

I have this 2 input boxes:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input autofocus placeholder="<?php echo CITY_COUNTRY;?>" class="form-control" onkeydown="return handleEnter(this, event)" type="text" id="search" name="country" value="<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['location_name'])){echo $_REQUEST['location_name'];}?>" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon" onClick="jQuery('#chckin').datepicker('show');">
            <input id="chckin" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['checkin_name'])){echo $_GET['checkin_name'];}else{echo date("j/n/Y");}?>" name="checkIn" style="display:none;" />
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
        </span>
        <input type="text" id="check_in" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['checkin_name'])){echo $_GET['checkin_name'];}else{echo date("j/n/Y");}?>" class="form-control" disabled="disabled"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I write in the first one, appear an autocomplete with information. The problem is that when It load, on the form-group it works ok but on the second one, the input is above the autocomplete..

Could it be a problem with the input-group class?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on class : form-control on this input

```
<input type="text" id="check_in" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['checkin_name'])){echo $_GET['checkin_name'];}else{echo date("j/n/Y");}?>" class="form-control" disabled="disabled"/>
```

I changed the property `position: relative;` to `position: static;`